# Redirect the user immediately to another page

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to redirect the user if they are not logged in.

**app-routing.modules.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {SearchComponent} from './search/search/search.component';
import {RegisterComponent} from './register/register.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {LoginGuard} from './login/login.guard';
import {ProfileComponent} from './profile/profile.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'edit-profile', component: ProfileComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**login.guard.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {SearchComponent} from '../search/search/search.component';
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import {LoginService} from './login.service';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private searchComponent: SearchComponent, private cookieService: CookieService, private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router, private location: Location) {
  }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
    return this.hasAccess();
  }

  hasAccess() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.loginService.hasCookie(this.cookieService.get('login')).subscribe(hasCookie => {
        if (hasCookie === 1) {
          return new Promise(() => {
            this.loginService.getCookie().subscribe(cookieFromServer => {
              if (cookieFromServer === this.cookieService.get('login')) {
                if (this.location.path() === '/login' || this.location.path() === '/register') {
                  this.router.navigateByUrl('');
                  return resolve(false);
                } else if (this.location.path() === '/search') {
                  console.log('test');
                  this.router.navigateByUrl('');
                  return resolve(false);
                }
                return resolve(true);
              } else {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
                return resolve(false);
              }
            });
          });
        }
        if (this.location.path() === '/login' || this.location.path() === '/register') {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        } else if (this.location.path() === '/search') {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('');
        }
        return resolve(false);
      });
      return resolve(true);
    });
  }
}
```

My problem is, I visit the page /search and I may get redirected to the home page but it takes about 1 second, so I am still able to see the page /search, which should not be the case. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Canactivate accepts observable as return type, can you try to return the observable from your service instead of subscribing ? I did this in my app and the user does not see the page while the canactivate is working

Comment: @bmtheo not sure how I could return it as observable. As I see in the Angular documentation the return of canActivate() can be: Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree

Comment: You can do it like this ```return this.loginService.hasCookie(...).concatMap(hasCookie => this.loginService.getCookie().map(cookie => { if (cookie...) {return false;} return true;}));```

Answer (score 0):

The router will accept a `Promise<UrlTree>` so just resolve your promise with your desired route instead of calling `navigate()`

```
this.router.createUrlTree([''])
```

I tried to wire it in like below. Double check the paths for accuracy since

```
hasAccess() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.loginService.hasCookie(this.cookieService.get('login')).subscribe(hasCookie => {
            if (hasCookie === 1) {
                return new Promise(() => {
                    this.loginService.getCookie().subscribe(cookieFromServer => {
                        if (cookieFromServer === this.cookieService.get('login')) {
                            if (this.location.path() === '/login' || this.location.path() === '/register') {
                                console.log('test');
                                resolve(this.router.createUrlTree(['/']));
                            } else if (this.location.path() === '/search') {
                                console.log('test');
                                resolve(this.router.createUrlTree(['/']));
                            } else {
                                console.log('test');
                                resolve(true);
                            }

                        } else {
                            console.log('test');
                            return resolve(this.router.createUrlTree(['/']));
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
            if (this.location.path() === '/login' || this.location.path() === '/register') {
                console.log('test');
                resolve(this.router.createUrlTree(['/']));
            } else if (this.location.path() === '/search') {
                console.log('test');
                resolve(this.router.createUrlTree(['/']));
            }
            console.log('test');
            return resolve(false);
        });
        console.log('test');
        return resolve(true);
    });
}
```

https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Comment: I have tried that out. Before line #24 I have added a console.log. I see the message in the console, the page is /search and will not get forwarded.

Comment: Place a console long before every resolve(); It has to be hitting some other segment of code. Also change your path for redirects to '/'. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The browser prints 3x `test`. They're all from the last 3 console logs of your code. But I still don't get forwarded.

Comment: What happens if you remove the line it continuously hits?